# Was ist denn eine Brockenstube?

Tags: swiss-standard-german

Im Gespräch mit einem schweizer Kollegen tauchte kürzlich der Begriff *Brockenstube* auf - Das Wort scheint außerhalb der Schweiz nicht gebräuchlich zu sein - Was genau bedeutet das Wort uind wo kommt der Begriff her?

> Kürzlich habe ich in einer Brockenstube ein altes Gerät aufgetan.

Es scheint eine gewisse Verwandtschaft mit dem englischen Wort 'broker' und der französischen 'brocante' zu existieren.

PS: Ich muss zugeben, dass ich zuerst an eine "Hütte im Harz" gedacht habe. Inzwischen habe ich auch festgestellt, das sogar der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Brockenhaus) das Wort aufführt - Ein close request ist also vollkommen legitim. Ich lasse die Frage zur Erbauung der nichtschweizerischen Leser aber trotzdem erstmal stehen.

Comment: Ich bin ja wirklich kein Freund von Wikipedia-Verlinkungen, aber in diesem Fall... naja:  https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brockenhaus. Da steht: "Brockenhaus (oder Brockenstube oder Brockenhalle) ist in der Schweiz seit Ende des 19. Jahrhunderts eine Selbstbezeichnung vieler Gebrauchtwarenläden (Secondhand-Läden), in welchen sich preiswert gebrauchte Alltagsgegenstände erwerben lassen. Heute hat sich vielfach die Kurzbezeichnung Brocki etabliert."

Comment: Wahrscheinlich aus dem Französischen, vgl "bric-à-brac"

Comment: PS: ... Allerdings finde ich die Erklärung, die der Wikipedia-Artikel-Schreiber da so sorgfältig ausformuliert (Theologe Bodelschwingh soll einen Gebrauchtwarenladen so genannt haben, wobei er sich auf Johannes 6.12 gestützt habe, wo es um Brocken geht, die aufgesammelt werden) eher fragwürdig. Welche Bibelübersetzung hat Bodelschwingh verwendet? Steht da wirklich "Brocken"? Wie heißt das im griechischen Original oder in der in diesen Breiten über Jahrhunderte verwendeten lateinischen Form? ("Fragmenta" in der Vulgata.)

Comment: ... oder wen's im Kontext interessiert:  *(Iesus) dixit discipulis suis colligite quae superaverunt fragmenta ne pereant*. - "Brocken" ist dabei eigentlich eine komische Übersetzung. Die Leute waren hungrig, also haben sie (wenn man denn die ganze Story einmal als historisch voraussetzt) kaum ganze "Brocken" fallen lassen vom Brot, sondern allenfalls Krümel.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Das steht in mehreren Bibelübersetzungen: [Lutherbibel 2017](https://www.bibleserver.com/text/LUT/Johannes6%2C12), [Lutherbibel 1984](https://www.bibleserver.com/text/LUT84/Johannes6%2C12), [Elberfelder Bibel](https://www.bibleserver.com/text/ELB/Johannes6%2C12), [Menge Bibel](https://www.bibleserver.com/text/MENG/Johannes6%2C12). In der Lateinischen [Vulgata](https://www.bibleserver.com/text/VUL/Johannes6%2C12), die der Ausgangspunkt vieler deutscher Übersetzungen ist, steht *»Colligite quæ superaverunt **fragmenta,** ne pereant.«*

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Es mussten ja wohl *Brocken* sein, die in die **Körbe** gefüllt wurden - *Krümel* wären durchgefallen.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Auch eine [griechische Version](http://www.diebibelonline.de/Bibeln/WH.php?Buch=Johannes&Kapitel=6) habe ich gefunden. Ich weiß aber nicht, ob das Neugriechisch oder das altgriechische Original ist. Dort steht jedenfalls *»ὡς δὲ ἐνεπλήσθησαν, λέγει τοῖς μαθηταῖς αὐτοῦ· συναγάγετε τὰ περισσεύσαντα **κλάσματα,** ἵνα μή τι ἀπόληται.«* Und *»κλάσμα«* heißt offenbar *»Bruch, Fragment«*.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: http://bibeltext.com/john/6-12.htm Und wenn Brocken immer groß wären, könnte man sie nicht auslöffeln.

Comment: @Carsten  Hier möchte ich widersprechen, und zwar aus eigener Anschauung: Die Brocken, die man mit der Suppe auslöffelt, sind Brotbocken von mundgerechter Größe. Sich Brot in die Suppe oder auch Milch zu brocken, ist eine Sitte, die ich von bäuerlicher Verwandtschaft in Süddeutschland gut kenne. (Ich gebe zu, dass dieser Gebrauch des Wortes Brocken meiner Kritik an der Bodelschwingh-Theorie entgegensteht. Das habe ich mir jetzt selbst eingebrockt...)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann, genau an diese Brocken dachte ich auch, insofern musst Du gar nicht widersprechen. Gut, dass wir uns einig sind :)

Comment: @tofro und die Frage der Krümel sowie des Siebmaßes von Körben in Palästina um's Jahr 30: Was ich sagen wollte ist, dass ich die Übersetzung *Brocken* für *fragmenta* (lat.) bzw. *klasma* (gr.) hier seltsam finde. Bzw. noch viel mehr, dass sich die Leute, die den Johannes zusammengeschrieben haben, nicht gut nachgedacht haben, denn wie gesagt, werden hungrige Leute ganze Brocken Brot liegenlassen? - Nun müsste man natürlich wissen, wass der gebildete Griechischsprecher oder -schreiber des 2. Jahrhunderts vor sich sah, wenn er *klasma* hörte... vielleicht doch Krümel?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Keine Ahnung, was du dir unter einem Brocken vorstellst - Aber "[Brot]brocken" ist die seit Jahrhunderten durchaus akzeptierte Übersetzung von *fragmentum [panis]*. Brocken kommt vom AHD *brocke* == "brechen" und ist damit sogar eine sehr wörtliche Übersetzung für *fragmentum*.